# Spring Security cannot be authenticated

Tags: java, spring-security

When the loadUserByUsername function return ShopmeUserDetails(user), then it cannot be authenticated. But when return the User details it works without issue.

Below not work, which return the new ShopmeUserDetails(user):

```
package co.ichat.ichatweb.impl;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import co.ichat.ichatweb.model.ShopmeUserDetails;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.model.User;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.repository.UserRepository;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.service.IUserService;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService, UserDetailsService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Integer saveUser(User user) {
        String passwd= user.getPassword();
        String encodedPasswod = passwordEncoder.encode(passwd);
        user.setPassword(encodedPasswod);
        user = userRepo.save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) 
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        Optional<User> opt = userRepo.findUserByEmail(email);
        
        if(opt.isEmpty())
        {
                
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email: " +email +" not found !");
                
        }
        else {
            User user = opt.get();
            // return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            //      user.getEmail(),
            //      user.getPassword(),
            //      user.getRoles()
            //      .stream()
            //      .map(role-> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
            //      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            // );
            return new ShopmeUserDetails(user);
        }
        
    }
}
```

And below work:

```
package co.ichat.ichatweb.impl;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import co.ichat.ichatweb.model.ShopmeUserDetails;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.model.User;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.repository.UserRepository;
import co.ichat.ichatweb.service.IUserService;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService, UserDetailsService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Integer saveUser(User user) {
        String passwd= user.getPassword();
        String encodedPasswod = passwordEncoder.encode(passwd);
        user.setPassword(encodedPasswod);
        user = userRepo.save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) 
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        Optional<User> opt = userRepo.findUserByEmail(email);
        
        if(opt.isEmpty())
        {
                
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email: " +email +" not found !");
                
        }
        else {
            User user = opt.get();
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    user.getRoles()
                    .stream()
                    .map(role-> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            );
            //return new ShopmeUserDetails(user);
        }
        
    }
}
```

And below is the ShopmeUserDetails class:

```
package co.ichat.ichatweb.model;

import java.util.\*;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class ShopmeUserDetails implements UserDetails {
private User user;

    public ShopmeUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    //Issue with below function
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<String> roles = user.getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }
    
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return user.getId();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }

}
```

Why it cannot be authenticated when we return ShopmeUserDetails(user)

Comment: `then it cannot be authenticated` i have absolutely no idea what you mean by this statement, authenticated when doing what? what is it? the user? a client? Also, enable DEBUG logs and update your question with the full debug logs so that we can actually see what it is you are trying to do. Your question header is suggesting that it is Spring Security that is authenticating? Spring security is a library, it cant authenticate itself. Users or clients authenticate themselves, not libraries.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`user.isEnabled()` might be a possible error. Try this

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```